# How can I deliver data to different HTML pages with only one PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I want to use the same PHP page to get values from a MySQL table to different pages... and I am using the following PHP code. sendResult is a variable which tells to the PHP page what info want to recieve, the first things that do the others pages is to "shout" what info they want.

```
$sendResult = $_POST['getResult'];

    if ($sendResult ==="0"){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['section']==="0") {
          $timestamp = strtotime($row['created']);
          $cdate = date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
          $ctime = date('H:i', $timestamp);
          echo "<div>";
          echo "<div class='box-header justify-content-between'>";
          echo "<p class='mr-4 mb-0 font-weight-bold'>Name LastName</p>";
          echo "<p class='ml-4 mb-0'>" . $cdate . " - " . $ctime . " hs.</p></div>";
          echo "<div class='box-msg'><p>" . $row['msg'] . "</p></div></div>";
        }
      }
    }
    if ($sendResult ==="1"){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['section']==="1") {
          echo "<p>write something else</p>";
          echo "<p>with some value for example: " . $row['something'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p>and finish the text.</p>"; 
        }
      }
    }
    if ($sendResult ==="2"){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['section']==="2") {
          // write another things
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there any way to do it better? I modified a code that I used to use when I had 1 PHP page for each html page, so I had only the while with the if inside, and if the row were for that page, this delivered the data.

Now I added another if upper per page that I want to deliver data, but I'm wondering if maybe inside the first "if" could I use a "for" and get only the rows with the field (0, 1, or 2) that I want for that specific page, but obviously I haven't tried it yet because I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: You are using IF statements to determine the entire page contents?

Comment: The upper IF is always to tell the PHP file what info the other page is requesting, and the inside IF (under the while) is to select the rows that has only that value (0,1 or 2) in "section" field of mySql database.

Comment: In my opinion this just looks messy. What happens when you have even more types of `$sendResult`? Your gonna chain more and more IF statements? This would be very hard to upkeep, much better to have multiple files if the entire page content is different when different things are passed to it

Comment: I hadn't think about it! In this case I will have only 3 pages for requering info, but is a good thing to keep in mind in case I got more  in another proyect.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in separate functions, and use `switch/case` to call them.

```
switch($sendResult) {
case "0":
    do_something($result);
    break;
case "1":
    do_something_else($result);
    break;
case "2":
    do_another_thing($result);
    break;
default:
    die("unrecognized getResult=$sendResult");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this function! I will try to code it now and then I tell you, but I think it is exactly what I was looking for.